# What happens to child views when parent is dismissed in Android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-view, onclicklistener

I have a custom view in android which is also a container for other views. The child views have certain onClickListeners  attached to them. My question is when the parent view is dismissed, does the associated child views and their corresponding listeners also cleaned up or do we need to handle it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically any View can be considered as ViewGroup hierarchy with child elements in it. If by "dismissed" your custom View is removed through the call of ViewGroup#removeView (or any similar removal methods) then all its children are removed too.